# binomial - parameters at which american option hits early exercise possibility

Tags: option-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory, binomial-tree, binomial

I am looking for a set of parameters (d,u,r,So,K, N=?) for pricing an american call using binomial where the call hits the early exercise possibility.

Do you have any exemplary set?

Comment: Wild guess: if the remaining time value of the option is the less than interest rate on the in-money value, exercising early would make sense.

Comment: I am looking for an example where the early exercise of a call is possible just to see that the  exercise is not an optimal strategy and the call should be hold until maturity (American=European call) as opposed to the put option where the exercise is profitable once it hits the exercise region.

Answer (score 1):

you need a positive dividend rate or a negative interest rate. Without these, it is a model-free result that early exercise is never optimal for a call option.